# PubNub + GCM Push notifications vs. regular PubNub messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am looking for some clarification about using PubNub and GCM together effectively. I have already set up my app as explained in [this PubNub guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/), and it is working 100%. However I now need to insert my own code into this thing and I am wondering if there is a clear-cut way to achieve what I want from this.

- If the app is in the foreground, receive message as normal and update UI as normal. When app is in the background however, send a GCM push with the message payload as an extra in the pendingIntent. Please understand I am not asking how to detect if the app is in the background/foreground.

My thoughts right now are to completely rely on the GCM push to carry my payload data, as it's redundant to send it twice. Subscribe would then only be called to join the channel where they will receive the push from. The onReceive of the receiver would check isAppInBackground and if so, call sendNotification. Is there a problem with doing it this way?

Currently **sending information with PubNub to a channel** is done like this:

```
 private void sendThatJSONInfo(String channelID){
    JSONObject jason = new JSONObject();

    try {

        jason.put("data1", aString);
        jason.put("data2", anotherString);
        jason.put("fromWho", username);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pN.publish(channelID, jason, new Callback() {
    });
}
```

**And to send a GCM** to that same channel, my code is like this:

```
 public void sendNotification(View view) {
    PnGcmMessage gcmMessage = new PnGcmMessage();
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jso.put("data1", aString);
        jso.put("data2", anotherString);
        jso.put("fromWho", username);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gcmMessage.setData(jso);

    PnMessage message = new PnMessage(
            pubnub,
            CHANNEL,
            callback,
            gcmMessage);
    try {
        message.publish();
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope my question is clear. I've condensed and repeated it below:

- Is there way to combine these two methods in order to receive a push when the app is in the background? I have some ideas but am wondering if there is already a best practice for this or at least a direction I can head towards.

Comment: so what you're saying is I remove the sending push method and add pn_gcm to my payload, can you please provide an example of that with the current example data I have. I am not a pro coder so I rely on examples or a clear explanation

Comment: that is very helpful thank you. I will play around with this and get back to you

Comment: quick question -  my flow would be like this: user sends pnGcmMessage (with just the title and type) added to a PnMessage which contains the rest of my data, then user receives PnMessage and depending if app is in background, either show push or update the UI. Only thing that hangs me up is dealing with the onClick of the push... I could have my intentService get the "type" and use a switch statement to deal with sending the rest of the payload to a pending intent before showing notification?

Comment: I have read it and have it running, my extra question there was more about the logic behind using a service like PubNub but that is something that I can and likely will discover on my own

Comment: Removed my comments and added official answer. If it was helpful, please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Sending GCM Push Notifications with PubNub Android SDK

You can create a `PnGcmMessage` and add it to a `PnMessage` that you publish. I prefer working with the raw `JSObject` and create all of the content myself without the helper methods, but this technique will easier for you. Also, please read the [Publishing to GCM with Java docs‌](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/mobile-gateway#Publishing_to_GCM)​?

Optionally, you can ignore the special method for sending push message and just [add `pn_gcm` content to the message payload in the publish](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call).

And this example, [Sending and Receiving Android Push Notifications w/ GCM](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/), should provide the details you require.